# An app that normally starts in 3 secs takes 3 mins to start straight after booting - why?

Tags: windows, image, visual-c++, mfc

I kinda know the simple answer to this question, but am struggling to find detailed information to guide me to a solution.

My (C++, MFC) app is run from a folder which contains several gigabytes and several tens of thousands of files. Straight after boot, it can take up to 3 mins to start, but if you quit it and restart any time after that it only takes 2-3 seconds to start. If I run my app from an empy folder structure, it starts quickly regardless of when I run it.

I cannot see that Windows is spending a lot of system time and not giving my app processor time during the slow start up, but it may well be doing that. So the real questions are:

- how can I tell whether it is specifically my app that is taking the time... as opposed to my app just generally accessing a folder for the first time, whereupon Windows does a whole lot of time-consuming extra work over which my app will never have any control?
- if there is nothing problematic in my app, how can I rearrange my file/folder structures, or change Windows settings, to minimise the time that Windows takes? Put another way... where can I find information on what Windows does the first time it encounters a folder after boot?

I am running Windows XP Professional, but can't easily tell what motherboard, hard drive, etc I have got if that might make a difference.

Comment: The file system cache is a wonderful speed booster.  Fix the disk.

Comment: Intended level of helpfulness of above comment: 10. Actual level of helpfulness: 1. Reason: if I knew what was meant by "fix the disk" I would not be asking this question.

Comment: @omatai: Hans probably meant get a faster disk. If your folder has as many files as you say it does, the slowness might be Explorer trying to enumerate all the files. Windows generally starts pretty fast assuming it isn't bogged down with start-up crap at boot.

Comment: Wait a sec. Windows is not so dumb as to lick its lips at the sight of C: and go enumerating all the files on the entire disk. It has limits - maybe it searches only N folders deep. It would be helpful to know what those limits are (what is N?). My app does not need all the files and folders to be accessible all the time. So.... surely if I can understand what Windows is doing, I can fix the file structure, and save myself a lot of time and $$ that I would waste by "fixing the disk". Other apps started at boot up are starting fine. The disk is not the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The application directory is special. It is the first directory searched when it comes time to load a DLL, for example. And searching for a DLL in a directory containing tens of thousands of files is probably going to be slower than searching for a DLL in a mostly-empty directory.

It's faster the second time because by then the contents of the directory have been loaded into the disk cache.

I'm kind of confused by the your second question, since you already answered it when you wrote "If I run my app from an empty folder structure, it starts quickly regardless of when I run it." But I'll repeat it: "Get the unnecessary junk out of your application directory."

Comment: How deep does Windows go searching in the application directory for DLLs? There are probably 50 files and folders in this directory... but those folders ultimately contain tens of thousands and gigabytes worth of files.

Comment: Only the application directory itself. It doesn't search subdirectories. (Check your PATH, maybe there are some big directories on your PATH?)